# my db is not INSERTing some values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I have the following codes:

```
   $query = "INSERT INTO main_table (id, matric_no, session, semester, 
                                    course_name, test, exam,practical)
       VALUES (NULL, '$_POST[matric_no]', '$_SESSION[session]', 
              '$_SESSION[semester]', '$_SESSION[course_name]', '$_POST[test]',
              '$_POST[exam]', '$_POST[practical]')";

       mysql_query($query) or
       die (mysql_error());
```

Then I tried:

```
       echo "$_POST[semester]";
       echo "$_POST[course_name]" ;
```

and they echoed out what I was expecting but not INSERTing INTO the database.. Only those two.

Thanks.

Comment: What types are the columns? Also, never insert POST values directly. See  http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: what exactly do you mean by columns? The first session value inserted.

Comment: What types are the database fields

Comment: yes i can see the mistake. I used INT instead of VARCHAR... Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem was a column type mismatch that wasn't visible in the original question.

However, it is a very bad idea to insert POST or other values directly - always run `mysql_real_escape_string()` (or whatever sanitation function your database library provides) on them. More on SQL injections [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: @Martin I only answered it because there was no correct one to tick - I initially suggested deleting the question altogether.

Comment: ah, I have meant "Why did you mark this as community wiki answer?", sorry.

Comment: @Martin yeah, I understood what you meant. No specific reason, I was just annoyed about the existing answers (one of which was accepted) so I chose to shove one in for accepting. It wouldn't have had to be CW though.

Answer (score -1):

This code should give you a syntax error...

```
   echo "$_POST[semester]";
   echo "$_POST[course_name]" ;
```

Try this

```
   echo "{$_POST['semester']}";
   echo "{$_POST['course_name']}" ;
```

or this:

```
   echo "xxx".$_POST['semester']."xxx";
   echo "xxx".$_POST['course_name']."xxx;
```

More information here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Mind that $_POST[xxx] is note the proper syntax !!! Read docs above!

Comment: Not true. This *is* proper syntax to address an array inside a string.

Comment: Peter - have you tried `echo "$_POST[semester]";`? It works. It's not the problem (although examples 2 and 3 are much better style, no doubt)

Comment: ... but removing downvote because it's still way better than the other one